# Use of JSON-P with Sensitive Information

Tags: ajax, json, security, rest, jsonp

I have a secured website that requires a user to authenticate, and would like to return sensitive data to the client from my API via JSON-P so that I can get around ajax cross-domain issues.  I own both the client and server, so I am not concerned about the security from the client perspective (i.e. reading malicious js from the server).

I have been researching ways to secure the JSON-P to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery, but haven't been able to clearly determine whether checking the Referer is a foolproof method for securing the data. As I understand it, the Referer header cannot be spoofed in this situation because the calls would be from javascript, and Headers cannot be changed.  Is this a correct assumption?

I would like some clear-cut examples of why or why not checking the Referer would/wouldn't work to secure JSON-P.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just to clarify - the JSON-P is secured via Spring Security, so it wouldn't only be secured by the Referer header.  I am mostly concerned here about session hijacking...

Comment: You should look into OAuth, which basically takes the idea of checking the referer one step further by using a signed token.

Comment: I've considered OAuth, which would probably let us use JSON (instead of 'with padding'). We're currently using CAS and I'd like to use that, but so far it's been a bear trying to get it to work with AJAX calls to get plain JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsonp urls can be called using normal curl code. Http refer can easily be forged.

Comment: Yes, but if you call the JSON-P from a normal client, then you'll have to authenticate first, so I don't think curl would work. The only way someone could get the data that shouldn't have access would be to hijack an existing session and then spoof the referer, which I assume would be via Javascript.

Comment: @acvcu Does that mean that the url contains some kind of session information when logged in?

Comment: No, the URL itself doesn't have any session information when logged in.  It uses JSESSIONID cookie.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like some clear-cut examples of why or why not checking the Referer would/wouldn't work to secure JSON-P.

`Referer` is not guaranteed to be sent, so:

- if you require it to be present and match a trusted site, you will be breaking the app for everyone whose browser or network setup doesn't send it;
- if you permit it to be absent to get around that, you open yourself to attack not just for those users, but for everyone where the attacker can induce Referer not to be sent (most notably, from HTTPS pages;
- also, to behave properly with proxies you would have to `no-cache` all your responses (or `Vary: Referer`, but that won't work right in IE)

Referrer-checking is a weak and problematic method which sometimes sees use as a desperate last measure... it's not something you should build when you've got the choice. If you control both servers you can easily include a request token on one page that gets recognised by the script on the either.